# how to open side menu bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and I have created a menu button to open a side menu but however, I need some help to make it happen.

Can anyone help me implemented or guide me in my code of how to make it work. please and thank you very much!

Here is my code:

```
  Widget _icon(IconData icon, {Color color = LightColor.iconColor}) {
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(13)),
      color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      boxShadow: AppTheme.shadow),
  child: Icon(
    icon,
    color: color,
  ),
);
}
```

> Main:

```
    class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  bool isHomePageSelected = true;
  Widget _appBar() {
    return Container(
      padding: AppTheme.padding,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          RotatedBox(
            quarterTurns: 4,
            child: _icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.black54),
          ),
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(13)),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Color(0xfff8f8f8),
                      blurRadius: 10,
                      spreadRadius: 10),
                ],
              ),


            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `GlobalKey()` and call `_key.currentState.openDrawer();`

code snippet

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();
...
child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          _key.currentState.openDrawer();
        },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  Widget _icon(IconData icon, {Color color = Colors.blue}) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(13)),
        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        //boxShadow: AppTheme.shadow
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          _key.currentState.openDrawer();
        },
        child: Icon(
          icon,
          color: color,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool isHomePageSelected = true;
  Widget _appBar() {
    return Container(
      //padding: AppTheme.padding,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          RotatedBox(
            quarterTurns: 4,
            child: _icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.black54),
          ),
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(13)),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Color(0xfff8f8f8),
                      blurRadius: 10,
                      spreadRadius: 10),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      appBar: AppBar(leading: _appBar()),
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. Also, can you explain what does the `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> ` do ?

Comment: We use the GlobalKey Class to access and manipulate the state of our Form and the outer Scaffold Widget.  you can reference this https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@tensor/using-global-keys-to-get-state-and-validate-input-in-dart-s-flutter-framework

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
```

Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/openDrawer.html

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to call      `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();`

Sample Code:

```
drawer: const NavBar(), // Your nav bar here
appBar: AppBar(
          title: "Home".appBarText(),
          leading: Builder(builder: (context) {
            return IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
              onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); 
              },
        );
```